# Perl edit an XML file: search and replace

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I am trying to add some fields to an `open office` file by editing the `contents.xml` file that is generated when unzipping the writer. The open office file has a pretty simple format

```
  Incident Form 



    Date: 
    Operator:
    Patient Name: 
    No: 
    Database Number:
```

and I would like to change it to the something like the following

```
Incident Form 



    Date: 15/08/2013
    Operator: John Doe
    Patient Name: Jane Doe
    No: 1234567891
    Database Number:db165489
```

The various fields Date, Operator etc will be extracted from a database.

The `xml` file looks gobbledegook to me and seems to be printed to a single line. I know I shouldn't use regex to substitute values and an xml parser should be used. How can I change the `Date` column to `Date: $todays_date`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rpt="http://openoffice.org/2005/report" xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:tableooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/table" xmlns:field="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooo-ms-interop:xmlns:field:1.0" xmlns:formx="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooxml-odf-interop:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:css3t="http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/" office:version="1.2"><office:scripts/><office:font-face-decls><style:font-face style:name="StarSymbol" svg:font-family="StarSymbol" style:font-pitch="variable" style:font-charset="x-symbol"/><style:font-face style:name="LucidaSans1" svg:font-family="LucidaSans"/><style:font-face style:name="OpenSymbol" svg:font-family="OpenSymbol"/><style:font-face style:name="Times New Roman" svg:font-family="&apos;Times New Roman&apos;" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable"/><style:font-face style:name="Arial" svg:font-family="Arial" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable"/><style:font-face style:name="DejaVu Sans" svg:font-family="&apos;DejaVu Sans&apos;" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/><style:font-face style:name="HG-MinchoL" svg:font-family="HG-MinchoL" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/><style:font-face style:name="LucidaSans" svg:font-family="LucidaSans" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/></office:font-face-decls><office:automatic-styles><style:style style:name="P1" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard"><style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/><style:text-properties fo:font-size="14pt" style:text-underline-style="solid" style:text-underline-width="auto" style:text-underline-color="font-color" fo:font-weight="normal" style:font-size-asian="14pt" style:font-weight-asian="normal" style:font-size-complex="14pt" style:font-weight-complex="normal"/></style:style><style:style style:name="P2" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard"><style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="start" style:justify-single-word="false"/><style:text-properties fo:font-size="14pt" style:text-underline-style="none" fo:font-weight="normal" style:font-size-asian="14pt" style:font-weight-asian="normal" style:font-size-complex="14pt" style:font-weight-complex="normal"/></style:style><style:style style:name="P3" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard"><style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/><style:text-properties fo:font-weight="normal" style:font-weight-asian="normal" style:font-weight-complex="normal"/></style:style><style:style style:name="P4" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard"><style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/><style:text-properties fo:font-size="10.5pt" style:text-underline-style="none" fo:font-weight="normal" style:font-size-asian="10.5pt" style:font-weight-asian="normal" style:font-size-complex="10.5pt" style:font-weight-complex="normal"/></style:style><style:style style:name="P5" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard"><style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/><style:text-properties fo:font-size="12pt" style:text-underline-style="none" fo:font-weight="normal" style:font-size-asian="12pt" style:font-weight-asian="normal" style:font-size-complex="12pt" style:font-weight-complex="normal"/></style:style><style:style style:name="P6" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard"><style:paragraph-properties fo:margin-left="0.5083in" fo:margin-right="0in" fo:text-align="end" style:justify-single-word="false" fo:text-indent="0in" style:auto-text-indent="false"/><style:text-properties fo:font-size="14pt" style:text-underline-style="none" fo:font-weight="normal" style:font-size-asian="14pt" style:font-weight-asian="normal" style:font-size-complex="14pt" style:font-weight-complex="normal"/></style:style><style:style style:name="P7" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard" style:list-style-name="L1"><style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="start" style:justify-single-word="false"/><style:text-properties fo:font-size="14pt" style:text-underline-style="none" fo:font-weight="normal" style:font-size-asian="14pt" style:font-weight-asian="normal" style:font-size-complex="14pt" style:font-weight-complex="normal"/></style:style><style:style style:name="T1" style:family="text"><style:text-properties fo:font-weight="bold" style:font-weight-asian="bold" style:font-weight-complex="bold"/></style:style><text:list-style style:name="L1"><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="1" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="0.5in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="0.5in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="2" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="0.75in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="0.75in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="3" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="1in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="1in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="4" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="1.25in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="1.25in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="5" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="1.5in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="1.5in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="6" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="1.75in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="1.75in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="7" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="2in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="2in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="8" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="2.25in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="2.25in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="9" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="2.5in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="2.5in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet><text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="10" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" text:bullet-char="•"><style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment"><style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" text:list-tab-stop-position="2.75in" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="2.75in"/></style:list-level-properties><style:text-properties style:font-name="StarSymbol"/></text:list-level-style-bullet></text:list-style></office:automatic-styles><office:body><office:text><office:forms form:automatic-focus="false" form:apply-design-mode="false"/><text:sequence-decls><text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/><text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Table"/><text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Text"/><text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Drawing"/></text:sequence-decls><text:p text:style-name="P1">Incident Form </text:p><text:p text:style-name="P5"/><text:p text:style-name="P4"/><text:p text:style-name="P3"/><text:p text:style-name="P2">Date: </text:p><text:p text:style-name="P2">Operator:</text:p><text:p text:style-name="P2">Patient Name: </text:p><text:p text:style-name="P2">CHI: </text:p><text:p text:style-name="P2">Database Number:</text:p><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2">Details Of Event: <text:s/>(include procedures/scans performed on patient)</text:p><text:list xml:id="list19144931451" text:style-name="L1"><text:list-item><text:list><text:list-item><text:p text:style-name="P7"/></text:list-item><text:list-item><text:p text:style-name="P7"/><text:p text:style-name="P7"/><text:p text:style-name="P7"/></text:list-item></text:list></text:list-item></text:list><text:p text:style-name="P2">Scan Performed: <text:s/>No <text:span text:style-name="T1"><text:s text:c="8"/></text:span></text:p><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2">Letter required for GP/consultant? <text:s/>No</text:p><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2">Follow Up Requirements: </text:p><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P2"/><text:p text:style-name="P6"/></office:text></office:body></office:document-content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a parser. For example, using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open contents.xml ;
$d = //text:p[contains(.,'Date:')] ;
insert text "15/08/2013" append $d ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same using `XML::LibXML` as this is included in the yum repository for RHEL5 whereas `XML::XSH2` - this would make it easier to use the perl script on all machines on our network

Comment: @moadeep: Sure. It is just much more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

There are modules to process Open Office documents.The synopsis of [OpenOffice-OOdoc](https://metacpan.org/module/JMGDOC/OpenOffice-OODoc-2.125/OODoc.pod) seems to be really close to what you want to do.